# Creating a PDF using using XML data, XSLT and xsl-fo

Tags: xml, pdf, xslt, xmltable

I'm trying to create a PDF sheet from XML Data. The bit I am struggling on is to create separate tables for different currencies.

I have managed to create a simple table with a header that pulls all the data through but now I'm trying to get it to pull only specific data through.

**DATA.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<StockFile>
   <Customer>
       <Supplier>A</Supplier>
       <Currency>US DOLLAR</Currency>
       <Deposit>0</Deposit>
       <Balance>0</Balance>
       <January>0</January>
       <February>0</February>
       <March>0</March>
       <April>0</April>
       <May>0</May>
       <June>0</June>
       <July>62</July>
       <August>18</August>
       <September>0</September>
       <October>0</October>
       <November>0</November>
       <December>77</December>
       <Total>157</Total>
       <Notes></Notes>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
       <Supplier>B</Supplier>
       <Currency>Euro</Currency>
       <Deposit>0</Deposit>
       <Balance>0</Balance>
       <January>0</January>
       <February>0</February>
       <March>0</March>
       <April>11</April>
       <May>94</May>
       <June>0</June>
       <July></July>
       <August>18</August>
       <September>0</September>
       <October>0</October>
       <November>0</November>
       <December></December>
       <Total>123</Total>
       <Notes></Notes>
    </Customer>
```

**Stylesheet.xsl**

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

   <xsl:stylesheet
        version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
        xmlns:fmt="http://xml.apache.org/xalan/java/com.ims.fop.Formatting">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>

<!-- REPORT BODY HEADER-->
    <xsl:template name="Body">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:block border="solid" border-after-width.conditionality="retain" border-before-width.conditionality="retain">
            <fo:table keep-together="auto" table-omit-footer-at-break="true" xsl:use-attribute-sets="normal-text">
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                    <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>         
                <fo:table-column column-width="1.6cm"/>         
                <fo:table-header>
                    <xsl:call-template name="backgroundheader"/>
                    <fo:table-row xsl:use-attribute-sets="h2">
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Supplier</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Deposit/Paid</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Bal to Pay</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Jan</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Feb</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Mar</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Apr</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>May</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>June</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>July</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Aug</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Sept</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Oct</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Nov</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Dec</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Total</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block>Notes</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                    </fo:table-row>
                    <xsl:template match="USHeader"/>
                </fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-body>
                <!--Not sure what to put in this section-->

                </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template >
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="USHeader">
    <fo:table-row xsl:use-attribute-sets="h2">
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding">$<fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="EUROHeader">
    <fo:table-row xsl:use-attribute-sets="h2">
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell xsl:use-attribute-sets="cell-padding"><fo:block></fo:block></fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That is the main bulk of my code, I've tried doing

```
 <xsl:key name="grpCur" match="Customer" use="Currency"/>
```

That doesn't work

```
<xsl:for-each select="Customer[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('grpCur', Currency))[1])]">
```

I'm at a lost where to go from here as I'm not overly confident with the XSLT as a language.

Comment: [mcve] You are calling a function named `backgroundheader` but isnt in your code... Try to complete your question. _but now I'm trying to get it to pull only specific data through_ <-- please specify with code or words! What is your expected result/outcome?

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer this for me it turns out the I have a namespace which is why it wasnt working.